# Cordova/Ionic2 project created from GIT repo

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cli

I developed a ionic2 application, I pushed it to a private git repo accessible by our team.
When another colleague is downloading this project, he is not able to use the ionic/cordova commands. (he has ionic/cordova installed globally so it's not this problem, I even tried on my machine by creating another repo and didn't work)

> Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

I know that ionic start/cordova create adds something more than what is uploaded to git, but this commands come with a `.gitignore` file that will ignore those files.

Is there any way to initiate the ionic application having the code from the private git?

I saw that `ionic cli` has a command: `ionic start --template` (which specifies a template) - Starter templates can either come from a named template, (ex: tabs, sidemenu, blank), a Github repo, a Codepen url, or a local directory.

This doesn't work as expected or I am not trying the right way.

Did anyone have the same problem and got a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no need to create the www folder and to put it on github.

The steps for cloning the Ionic2 application from a git repo are the following:

1. Git Clone
2. `npm install`
3. `ionic build` (which will create the www folder and the build structure inside it)
4. `ionic platform add <platform>`
5. `ionic build <platform>`

It worked for myself, without changing the ionic2 `.gitignore` or to have a www with `.gitkeep` as Andreas suggested (which is actually one of the solutions).

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `www` folder in your root directory, then run your build command.

If that works just add the www folder to your git repo by placing a `.gitkeep` file in it.

Comment: I knew about this solution tried this yesterday and didn't work but today I built everything again like you said and it works great. Thank you for your help!